# Arranging elements in the list

Tags: coq

I am arranging natural number list in descending order.
With the help of following two functions, I found the
maximum value element in the list.

Now instead of `fold_` tactic, I want to use my own function, because both are for same purpose.

```
Definition replace (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat:=
 match l with
 | nil => l
 | h::tl => if n <? h then l else n::tl
end.

Fixpoint largest (elements: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
match l with
| nil => 0
| cons h1 nil => h1 
| cons h l => match elements with
| O => h
| S elements' => largest elements'  (replace h l)
 end
 end.

Definition maxvalue (l : list nat) : [] <> l -> nat.
 intros.
 destruct l.
 destruct (H (@erefl (list nat) [])).
 apply : (fold_left (fun x y => if x <=? y then y else x) l n).
Defined.

Theorem sub_ordering : forall l n0 n1,
  n1 <= n0 -> 
  fold_left (fun x y : nat => if x <=? y then y else x) 
  l n1 <= fold_left (fun x y : nat => if x <=? y then y else x) l n0.

 Definition maxval (l : list nat) : [] <> l -> nat.
  intros.
  destruct l.
  destruct (H (@erefl (list nat) [])).
  apply : ( largest (length elements)(replace h l) l n).
 Defined.
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what your problem is? You do not say where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you edit your first message instead? It is not legible here. Basically you should try to give as small an example as possible. With the script, not a description of it.

Comment: apply :fold_left (fun x y : nat => if x <=? y then y else x) l n0.
 apply :(fold_left (largest (length elements)(replace h l)) l n). 
How to define h is nat? 
If in this way,then their is error apply : 
(fold_left (h:nat => largest (length elements)(replace h l)) l n).I want to make both statements compatible.